# Need help in passing objects to a python class method

Tags: python

I have a following code. It is very simple. I am just pasting a sample code

```
class Export:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
    def func1(self, dataset):
        # using self.df somewhere in the function
        print(dataset.value)

class Import2:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
    def func2(self, dataset):
        # using self.df somewhere in the function
        print(dataset.value)



class dataset():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.value = 1
        self.export = Export("ada")

object1 = dataset("add")
object1.export.func1(object1) -> prints 1 which is expected
```

Problem: in the line `object1.export.func1(object1)` I am passing `object1` as  a argument to method func1. I do not want to pass object1 again as an argument but want to access the object1 attributes. I want to access this like `object1.export.func1()` it should be able to use the attributes of object1

Instead of calling `object1.export.func1(object1)` where I am using object1 twice, I want to use it like `object1.export.func1()`

I could have used inheritance but I need below code to work

```
object1 = dataset("add")
object1.export.func1(object1)
make some changes to object1.df
These changes should be visible to both the classes Import and Export
```

**Edit**: I edited the pasted code above. It is working fine but need a solution for my problem

Comment: neither `Export` nor `Import2` classes have an attribute of `value` so why do those methods have an argument `self`? they shouldn't have that. also there is no way that `object1.export.func1` would print anything, it would raise a `TypeError`

Comment: @Matiiss: I edited the code. Its just a sample code I pasted

Comment: Yea there's lots wrong here OP. The error I get `TypeError: func1() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` which is expected.

Comment: Please link the original source if possible because I think you've changed the indents, it doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: Please check it now. I edited.

Comment: @Matiiss: Is my explanation not clear?

Comment: now I understand but you are basically asking to have an argument added to `Export` that will take the `dataset` class

Comment: @Matiiss True, but the context of where OP got this code would be helpful regardless.

Comment: @Matiiss: Instead of calling object1.export.func1(object1)  where I am using object1 twice, I want to use it like object1.export.func1().

Comment: Please write a more descriptive title. Like, what help do you need exactly? For tips, see [ask], like "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence".

Comment: You could add a parameter to the "Export" constructor with the "dataset" object in which the "Export" object is stored. "Export" object can store it as instance variable so that "func1" can use it later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you want to achieve with your code, but here's a way that satisfies your request:

```py
class Export:
    def __init__(self, df, dataset):
        self.df = df
        self.dataset = dataset

    def func1(self):
        # using self.df somewhere in the function
        print(self.dataset.value)


class dataset():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.value = 1
        self.export = Export("ada", self)


object1 = dataset("add")
object1.export.func1()
```

I would guess though that whatever your endgoal may be, that there are better ways of achieving it.

Comment: what are the better ways. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I don't know without context, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked

Answer (score 1):

In the given configuration I can propose this solution:

```py
class Export:
    def __init__(self, df, dataset=None):
        self.df = df
        self.dataset = dataset

    def func1(self):
        print(self.dataset.value)


class Dataset:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.value = 1
        self.export = Export("ada", dataset=self)


object1 = Dataset("add")
object1.export.func1()
```

You create an additional argument for the class that will handle the `Dataset`.
Also changed the code slightly to comply with PEP 8

Comment: I was missing this Export("ada", dataset=self). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe u need any kind of abstraction like:

```
class AbstracDF():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

class Export(AbstracDF):
    
    def func1(self):
        print(self.value)

class Import2(AbstracDF):

    def func2(self):
        print(self.value)
```